# Data transfer from a non-ros software to the ros environment

Tags: ros, communication

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

i am a beginner with ROS and I have a non-ROS application which calculates the position of a tag and i need to get this position data(x,y,z) into ROS environment, in order to use the ROS tools and libraries to develop further applications. This non-ROS positioning application(Server) provides the calculated data into some GUIs(Client) via TCP/IP Server-Client method by using sockets(localhost) to display the position of the tag. So my question is, how i could manage to create a communication between a non-ROS application with the ROS environment in order to manage the data transfer? If i would develop a ROS TCP/IP Client Node with the appropriate socket would it be possible to connect and communicate direct to the non-ROS positioning application Server and ask for the positioning data? I hope that i was clear enough.
Thank you very much in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/376051/data-transfer-from-a-non-ros-software-to-the-ros-environment/) by [staos](https://answers.ros.org/users/73277/staos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-04-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> If i would develop a ROS TCP/IP Client Node with the appropriate socket would it be possible to connect and communicate direct to the non-ROS positioning application Server and ask for the positioning data?

The short answer would be: yes.

This is done all the time, and we typically call these kinds of ROS nodes *bridges* (when connecting pieces of software) or *drivers* (when connecting ROS to (robot) hardware).

Be sure to check whether standard messages such as [geometry_msgs](http://wiki.ros.org/geometry_msgs) or TF2 can be used to represent the location of the tag instead of creating a new custom message. Using standard messages will make consumption by existing nodes much easier.

---

Edit:

> I hope it works because i found the rosbridge_suite a bit complex for this task.

`rosbridge` could also be used, but it depends a bit on how your "non-ROS application" works.

If it's under your control, and you can extend it with `rosbridge` compatibility, that could be a very lightweight way to be able to publish data to a ROS node graph without linking your/the "non-ROS application" to anything ROS (ie: `roscpp`).

If it's not under your control, and it only exposes some `tcp://` endpoints, then `rosbridge` would not really help that much.

> Actually the rosbridge_suite is useful only for Web applications?

No, not at all. It's just a simple JSON based protocol with a server which happens to "understand" ROS, allowing it to function (almost) as a transparent bridge and thereby allowing client applications to (almost) directly publish, subscribe and more without directly depending or importing any part of ROS itself.

> I mean, if i wanted to publish the position of the tag into some web page then i had to use the rosbridge_suite, right?

You *could* use `rosbridge` for that, yes. But that's mostly just because there is a well supported client implementation of the `rosbridge` protocol written in Javascript.

There's nothing inherently "web based" in `rosbridge`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [staos](https://answers.ros.org/users/73277/staos/) on 2021-04-17**:
Thank you very much for your fast response. I hope it works because i found the rosbridge_suite a bit complex for this task. Actually the rosbridge_suite is useful only for Web applications? I mean, if i wanted to publish the position of the tag into some web page then i had to use the rosbridge_suite, right? Thanks again.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-04-18**:
What made you revoke the `answered` status?

**Comment by [staos](https://answers.ros.org/users/73277/staos/) on 2021-04-29**:
Oh sorry that done by mistake. Thanks that you noticed.